# UISeachcontroller is not working in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I added UISearchController in UICollectionViewController. But when I am typing in searchBar it dismiss the keyboard. How can I use the UISearchController in UICollectionViewController with UISearchResultsUpdating protocol.

I tried to filterSearch on UICollectionView items. When I call , self.collectionview.reloadData(), on each keypress the keyboard dismisses.

Comment: show, what you have tried...

Comment: I added UISearchController to the header of the UICollectionView. Then tried to do realtime search. When I call self.collectionView.reloadData() the keyboard dismisses

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you call self.collectionView.reloadData()
all delegate methods are called including viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind hence your textfield will resign first responder.

you can refer

[CollectionViewWithSearchBar](https://github.com/ihomam/CollectionViewWithSearchBar)